# How to apply IFERROR to all cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have many cells that have #DIV/0! so I need to put the IFERROR function. Is there a way to apply this formula to all cells instead of putting the formula manually in every cell?

I tried this VBA code but I am looking for something more simple.

```
Sub WrapIfError()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim x As String

  If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    Set rng = Selection
    If Not rng.HasFormula Then GoTo NoFormulas
  Else
      On Error GoTo NoFormulas
        Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
      On Error GoTo 0
  End If

  For Each cell In rng.Cells
    x = cell.Formula
    cell = "=IFERROR(" & Right(x, Len(x) - 1) & "," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"
  Next cell

Exit Sub

'Error Handler
NoFormulas:
  MsgBox "There were no formulas found in your selection!"

End Sub
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: That code looks pretty good to me. What's the problem?

Comment: It's not a problem for me, but I would like to use something simple and teach other people that don't understand the basics of programming to apply it.

Comment: The only problem I could possibly think of is `x = Mid(cell.Formula, 2)` instead of `x = cell.Formula` in order to remove any leading `=` from the formula. Or - a bit more advanced - you could also use this: `Iif(InStr(1, cell.Formula, "=") > 0, Mid(selection.Formula, 2), cell.Formula)`.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps one of these versions will be easier to teach.

```
Sub apply_Error_Control()
    Dim cel As Range

    For Each cel In Selection
        If cel.HasFormula Then
            'option 1
            cel.Formula = Replace(cel.Formula, "=", "=IFERROR(", 1, 1) & ", """")"
            'option 2
            'cel.Formula = "=IFERROR(" & Mid(cel.Formula, 2) & ", """")"
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```

I've supplied two ways to apply the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) as a *'wapper'* for error control. To use the second option, comment the first and uncomment the second.

Select one or more cells and then run the macro; typically though <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> then <kbd>Run</kbd> from the worksheet.

Comment: @jainashish - it would appear you have more equals (e.g. `=`) signs than just a starting one in your formula. In those cases, simply use Option 2 or the adjusted Replace I've edited into Option 1.