# Add =IFERROR function to formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add =IFERROR function to Excel formulas. Example original formula in active cell: `=A1/B3`, example new formula: `=IFERROR(A1/B3;0)`. However it results in runtime error. The formula shown in the message box appears to be correct.

I've tested the same code for adding parentheses to formulas with the variables: `First_part = "=("   and   Last_Part = ")"`, which worked fine. I've also tested the same code with IF function using the variables:
`First_part = "=IF(F1=2;"  and Last_Part = ";0)"`, which also resulted in runtime error.

```
Sub Adding_IFERROR()

Dim Cell_Content As String
Dim First_Part As String
Dim Last_Part As String
Dim New_Cell_Content As String

First_Part = "=IFERROR("
Last_Part = ";0)"


'Remove the initial "=" sign from original formula
Cell_Content = ActiveCell.Formula
Cell_Content = Right(Cell_Content, Len(Cell_Content) - 1)

'Writing new formula
New_Cell_Content = First_Part & Cell_Content & Last_Part


MsgBox New_Cell_Content, vbOKOnly

ActiveCell.Formula = New_Cell_Content

End Sub
```

Is there any obvious reason to why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use commas instead of semicolons, when creating formulas by VBA.
So, change this:

```
Last_Part = ";0)"
```

to this:

```
Last_Part = ",0)"
```

Comment: Good catch! I was just about to mark this question as a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902128/how-to-apply-iferror-to-all-cells-in-excel/32902671#32902671) when I realized you'd uncovered the real reason  it was failing.

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours yesterday, I found the solution 5 seconds after posting the question.

Solution:

Last_Part = ",0"

I use semicolon ";" as separator in excel, but when inserting from VBA I had to use comma ",".